# Parse.com ErrorCode:141 function not found

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

I'm writing a code on android that calls a couple of functions to Parse.com's cloud code. Which is like this:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("appConfig", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void done(HashMap<String, Object> result, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> bizConfig = (HashMap)result.get("bizConfig");

                    if (bizConfig == null) {
                        Log.e("missing data","no bizConfig");
                        return;
                    }
                    List services = (List)bizConfig.get("services");
                    homeFragment.updateServices(services);
                } else {
                    Log.d("error: ", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

and on the cloud code side:

main.js

```
require('cloud/app.js');
require('cloud/validation.js'); // all beforeSaves
require('cloud/afterSave.js'); // all afterSaves
require('cloud/feature.js'); // all cloud code defines
```

feature.js

```
Parse.Cloud.define("appConfig", function(request, response) {
  response.success({
    bizConfig:bizConfig
  });
});
```

since main.js has required feature.js which has the 'appConfig' function, it should be working fine, and it had been. but after I updated some new code which has nothing to do with those codes above, on the android side, I kept getting this error: Error:141 function not found. I don't have any clue about it, and I searched about it, but I didn't get any answers related to the problem I currently have.

Is there anyone that can answer my bug?

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question.

I just put all of the codes from feature.js onto main.js, and then finally, Parse.com recognized those functions originally from feature.js. and I even moved those back to feature.js again, but those functions are still alive on Parse.com .

I guess it's just Parse.com's bug. don't know exactly what was wrong back there, but I fixed the problem.

for those who might have similar problems as I did.